# Getting thumbnails in wishlist to use parent image

Tags: magento-1.6, ce-1.6.2.0

We're using grouped products, and we have the configuration set to use the parent image for thumbnails in the shopping cart view.  This is working, but when we see those products in the wishlist, all we see is a placeholder image.

How can I make the thumbnail selection there work the same as on the cart page?

I have tried editing the wishlist/view.phtml to use:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getItemProductForThumbnail($item), 'small_image')->resize(113, 113);
```

instead of

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(113, 113);
```

but that breaks the page.  I get this in the system.log:

```
2014-09-18T18:15:30+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, null given, called in...
```

So I don't think $item is what `getItemProductForThumbnail($item)` is expecting

Comment: can you update the code?

Comment: then once you have some code then please update the question so we can help you

Comment: @KeyulShah Oh you meant upLOAD the code...I haven't changed anything, so the wishlist code should still be stock Magento...Let me see if I can find it...

Comment: not whishilt group product code buddy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17266/discussion-between-keyul-shah-and-david-wilkins).

Comment: Try changing `...init($product, 'small_image')->resize...` to `init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize` in /app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/wishlist/view.phtml

Comment: @R.S that changed it to the thumbnail placeholder image (it was previously the small_image placeholder)

Comment: Double check to make sure your item have image assigned to it

Comment: @R.S I can see the correct image when the item is moved to the cart

Comment: Did you check the parent to see if it have an image assigned to it?

Comment: Yes, it does.  As I said, the correct image appears when the item is in the shopping cart

Comment: Sorry... Does all the child items has image?

Comment: In System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout I have Grouped Product Thumbnail set to "Parent Product Thumbnail"  because they don't have their own images

Comment: Therefore on the wishlist the individual item does not have any image to display

Answer (score 3):

What your trying to do will require a lot of work

Take a look at /app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

To get the correct image magento  uses

```
 <img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(160, 155); ?>
```

`$this->getProductThumbnail()` is define in

**For Configurable item** -  app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer/Configurable.php

**For Group item** -  /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer/Grouped.php

**For Simple item** - /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php

In /app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/wishlist/view.phtml

You check the product type using $_product->getTypeId() the lookup the image according to `$this->getProductThumbnail()`

Comment: I see now that the method I was using is depricated...I will have to put in logic to try this answer and let you know how it works.